# Upgrading\Installing Swiftmailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I had a problem with an embedded image not appearing inline with swiftmail. Instead it was displayed after the content of the mail.
As I was on version 4.1.3, I decided to upgrade.

I did not understand the instructions to install using composer (I do not own the host server) and managed to download the zip file from Github.

Again the docs made little sense to me, so I copied all the files and folders from thi the zip file over my installation on the server.,

Swiftmail now causes an 'Internal Server Error' (no detail) and I can only assume that Swiftmailer needs a more advanced install.

As I originally installed Swiftmailer about 6 years ago I cannot remember how it was installed.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: There will probably be some information in the web server or PHP error logs. If you provide details of that, we should be able to work out the problem.

Comment: I have fixed the installation issue by deleting and re-copying the lib and root folders. Thanks for your reply.